# Why mriswith stayed (mostly) in Hagen Woods?

Tags: the-sword-of-truth

I've just finished reading Blood of the Fold.

In the end Richard and the gar army defeat the mirswith force in Aydindril. That made me wonder why until then the mriswith stayed close to the Hagen Woods. They were apparently waiting for the Sliph to wake and protecting their trapped queen, but 3000 years? In such a long time why didn't they seize the Old World and for example travel by sea? To Westland maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short answer

Prophecy

longer answer

Until Richard deactivated the towers travel between the new and old worlds was very difficult and possibly even impossible by sea (Im pretty certain the sister of the light mentioned that the energy traveled out across the sea) it is also probable that the woods offer some protection from gars

Answer (score 1):

Its because the Queen was stuck in the ruins in the woods individuals would go out exploring to find the one to help her escape.  more of their story in blood of the fold